# Console Messages in Pyppeteer

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, pyppeteer

I am trying to get all the console messages given a website URL using pyppeteer. However, All I can get are the responses with the 200-status code. I am using a website which has 4xx and 5xx responses as well, but the script does not return them.
I actually want to use a python script to extract all the js and ajax errors from a website. Is it possible using pyppeteer or possibly using some other library?

This is the code that I am using.

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch



async def on_console(msg):
    print('PAGE LOG:', msg.text)

async def on_page_error(error):
    print(error)

async def on_response(response):
    print(f"{response.status} {response.url}")
    


async def on_request_failed(request):
    failure = request.failure()
    if failure:
        print(failure.get('errorText', 'Unknown error'), request.url)
    else:
        print('Request failed without error information', request.url)

async def main():
    

    browser = await launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()

    page.on('console', lambda msg: asyncio.ensure_future(on_console(msg)))
    page.on('pageerror', lambda error: asyncio.ensure_future(on_page_error(error)))
    page.on('response', lambda response: asyncio.ensure_future(on_response(response)))
    page.on('requestfailed', lambda request: asyncio.ensure_future(on_request_failed(request)))

    try:
        await page.goto('https://toursthingstodo.com')
        await page.waitFor(5000)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

    await browser.close()


asyncio.run(main())
```

This is the response that I get.

```
200 https://toursthingstodo.com/
200 https://toursthingstodo.com/_next/static/css/cfeb154ff119552e.css
200 https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-3751418851639209
```

However, these are the errors that I have on my website.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXNUb.png)